# Load balancing Lucene.NET with an Asp.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, load-balancing, lucene.net

We want to start load balancing our website which currently uses lucene.net to store around 200k documents. We have an MVC website with some WCF services that perform the search and additional functionality.
How can load balancing be achieved and still use Lucene ?

I thought of 2 ways:

1. Having the index duplicated on every machine used to load balance
2. Storing the index on an external server, that would only hold this index to be used for searching.

Can you help me with some suggestions, explanations or anything useful?

Would any of the approaches mentioned above be more suitable, or are there any other solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

One alternative would be to use Elasticsearch (which itself uses Lucene under the hood).

This would be a bigger architectural change, but depending on your solution may still be trivial to bring in.

Elasticsearch would give you the load balancing out of the box, and you would not need to implement your own index synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the index on every machine but be wary that keeping the indexes in sync can be a pain. I have seen this approach used in other enterprise applications.

On the other hand a single instance of the index could create a bottleneck for searching.

In this case I would say pick your poison. I would probably try the single index and see how performance is affected. If that doesn't work then you'll have to go with duplicating the index and ensuring they're always in sync

Comment: would lucene struggle with a lot of searchers ? I was thinking having only one index would be easier to deal with

Comment: That's going to depend on your needs and the machine that the index is placed on. You'll want a machine with a sufficient amount of RAM and a high throughput network connection since those will be your most likely bottlenecks. Lucene works very well when placed on good hardware and configured properly.